# Import file without specifying the directory

Tags: import, files-and-directories

Consider a situation when we import some file in a .nb from a sub-directory located at the directory where .nb is located. We need to write specific path to the file. Next, suppose that we moved file to another directory. Then one needs to change the directory of the the file in .nb.

Is there any way to allow Mathematica to import the file simply by its name, without the specification of its location? I.e., to set up the file name and that the file is located somewhere in the .nb directory.

Comment: Have you tried using `NotebookDirectory[]` to refer to the the directory the notebook is currently in? You can use `FileNameJoin` to build up paths from there.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit : this requires to change the FileNameJoin each time when I move file to another directory. I would like to import file without taking care about specific path.

Comment: But that's my point: you use `NotebookDirectory[]` to refer to the current directory the notebook is in. If you move the notebook, `NotebookDirectory[]` will evaluate to the new directory and the relative paths stay the same.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit : I move not the notebook, but the file which I want to import from sub-directory A to sub-directory B. And I don't want each time to change the sub-directory in SetDirectory[];

Comment: In that case, I recommend you look up the documentation for `FindFile`.

Comment: `ParentDirectory` together with `NotebookDirectory` might be helpful.

Comment: Does `FileNames["file.ext", NotebookDirectory[], Infinity]` do what you're after?